# Convert Latitude Longitude to IMG Pixel Values Python

Tags: python, image, math, maps, weather

I'm working on a project that involves reading colored data from an image (I'll attach somewhere). The input needs to be in longitude latitude. It is important that I find a way to convert these coordinates to pixels in the image. I have been contemplating this issue a lot and no great solutions are popping in mind. Unfortunately, the raw data used to construct the image is not released. Any ideas? :)[Image I need to find color values for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4g4lJ.gif)

Edit: A problem here is that these images curve the earth so the latitude lines are not parallel lines. They have a curve.

Comment: You want to translate a geographic coordinate to  *pixel coordinates*? ... Project spherical coordinates on a plane? Your question is a bit broad.

Comment: Sorry for the broad question. Essentially, I am given a position in latitude and longitude. I need to find the specific pixel values that correspond to that position. For example, I need my program to recognize that lat = 40.7141667, long = -74.0063889 (New York's coordinates) is a certain pixel value on the image--in this case (573,310).

Answer (score 0):

One way that might work depending on your image is to use something similar to http://www.lat-long.com/ ,using Google maps to find a point. You will have to scale the image from google maps and overlay it on top of your image, and get the pixel value. You should be able to request an image with the proper level of zoom. The good news is that, since your image is static, you can hardcode the zoom level.